# What's the most efficient way for sending huge data from silverlight to the JavaScript environment of the browser?

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, silverlight-5.0

I have a Microsoft Silverlight application recording sound, obtaining that as chunks of byte Arrays.

What is the most efficient and reliable way to get this byte array from the Silverlight sandbox to the JavaScript environment?

My considerations so far:

- How much overhead is involved in calling a JavaScript method from within Silverlight?

  - Is there a recommended interval? Note that the data to be transferred would grow with the time as recording is still going on.
  - Is it possible to convert this Array directly into a `UInt8Array`?
- Would using Websockets over localhost be a viable option? How to implement the Server in Silverlight?
- Other ways?

Background is that `getUserMedia` [is still under review by Microsoft](http://status.modern.ie/getusermedia) and I'd like to avoid Flash and want to process the sound data using JS and not in Silverlight.

Edit: Now, *Media Capture and Streams* [**is being developed** for IE (but still not available)](https://status.modern.ie/mediacaptureandstreams?term=getUserMedia).

Comment: Implementing a high performance solution involving a typed Array and ignoring IE<10 is also worth a bounty.